# [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, offline

I'm using FireBase SDK as the backend for my app and I have enabled persistence as required.

```
[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

Offline mode was working well until recently when I started getting this error when using my app in offline mode.

```
2017-01-08 19:03:44.838 MyApp[1002] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170056710 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}, with Status Code: 0
```

This is easily reproducible. Just switch between airplane mode on the iPhone and you see this error.

I'm using CocoaPods to consume FireBase and here is the list of frameworks along with their versions.

```
-> Using Firebase (3.11.0)

-> Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)

-> Using FirebaseAuth (3.1.0)

-> Using FirebaseCore (3.4.6)

-> Using FirebaseDatabase (3.1.1)

-> Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix the firebase code, but I was able to wrap it in exception handling to stop it from crashing my app when the Internet connection on the device was turned off (specifically on an iPad2).

Objective C

```
            @try {
            [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"share" parameters:@{
        @"item_id" : [[[StatusReportIAPHelper sharedInstance] product] productIdentifier],
                 @"content_type" : @{@"title": [[[StatusReportIAPHelper sharedInstance] product] localizedTitle]}
              }];
             }
             @catch (NSException* exception) {
                 NSLog(@"SRS.logEventWithName Exception: %@ Reason: %@", exception.name, exception.reason);
             }
```

Swift 4

```
        do {
                Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
                    AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(bundleID!)" as NSObject
                    , AnalyticsParameterItemName: "\(bundleID!)" as NSObject
                    , AnalyticsParameterContentType:
                        "\(unquotedAppname!)" as NSString])
                }
                catch {
                    NSLog("POAD.logEvent Cannot log event - no Internet connection");
                }
```